# How to send sound from AUX or HDMI to Sonos

Tags: audio

I'm wondering if I could connect my Sonos One speaker to my TV to get better sound using my RPI 4.
This over HDMI or AUX from my TV to my RPI and then send that audio over WiFi to my Sonos One speaker.

Is this possible and what would I need to do this?

The idea is to replace my TV speakers for my Sonos One speaker as the Sonos speaker has much better quality than the built in TV speakers.

Comment: **You will never, ever, ever get the sound synced this way.**  I'd suggest a simpler solution would be to get a bluetooth transmitter that plugs into the sound out jack on the TV, if it has one, ~$25, **except** even with that there will be a noticeable lag that is disconcerting because the voices do not match the mouths.  *Even TV's that come with bluetooth have this problem,* so much so that they need additional features so you can tweak staggering the video, but the manufacturers tend to include disclaimers to the effect that this doesn't necessarily work very well.

Comment: @goldilocks My Sonos One speaker is a gen1, it doesn't have Bluetooth afaik. My TV does have Bluetooth. I'm using Jellyfin for my media and could sync the sound manually.

Comment: Get a used Sonos Connect on eBay.

Comment: The original Sonos One speakers do have an input jack on the back side (next to the headphone jack). So - if you've got (or can get) an audio output from your TV, that's what you need. IOW - this is a TV question, and not an RPi question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all I can answer your question - partly because your question confuses me - but I thought I'd post this to make you aware of some things that ***might*** get you moving in the direction you'd like.

**First**, as I mentioned in my comment, *some* Sonos 1 speakers have an audio input jack on the back - next to the headphone jack. Here's a picture of my *old* Play:5 unit. So - if you've got an audio output on your TV, you can probably plug it into this input jack.

[image: Play:5 speaker, rear view]

**Second**, there was a great hack done several years ago that resulted in the SoCo (Sonos Controller) project. The [original project](https://github.com/rahims/SoCo) was led by Rahim Sonawalla; that's been forked/evolved into the [current SoCo project](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo) (and [here](http://python-soco.com/)); also available as a [Python library through PIP](https://pypi.org/project/soco/).

So - if you're into Python, you can install a Python package on your RPi, and work toward implementation of the scheme you describe in your question.

**Third**, if your Sonos speakers don't have an audio input jack, and you're not into a Python/SoCo/DIY solution, you might want to take a look at a [Sonos Connect box](https://thehometheaterdiy.com/sonos-connect-amp/). But you should approach this option with *both eyes open* as Sonos has become a treacherous vendor - by that I mean they change their technology without regard for their customers.

One other thing I'll add, although not part of your question at all: The older Sonos hardware has some hardware design issues that cause them to fail. There's a good video ([youTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R8hKdGTIgQ)) describing how to repair the speakers. If you plan to use your speakers for a while, you'll need this guide sooner or later.

Comment: My Sonos One speaker doesn't have an audio input jack, only an ethernet port. It's a gen1, maybe gen2 has that? I will look into the SoCo project

Comment: @KenjiBailly: Huh?! My Sonos 1 speakers are all "old"; bought over a period of 4-5 years. Can you send a link to a picture of your speaker? Here's a [picture of my speaker](https://www.visionhifi.com.au/assets/images/product/large/43_5.jpg)

Comment: this is how mine looks https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2017/10/sonos-one-back-100739224-orig.jpg

Comment: @KenjiBailly: That's not a "Play 1' is it?

Comment: It's a Sonos One speaker as I mentioned

Comment: @KenjiBailly: Mmm - OK - that reminds me why I quit buying their products! :)  Have you looked into buying a [Sonos Connect unit](https://thehometheaterdiy.com/sonos-connect-amp/)? You may find this is a simpler solution for integrating RPi w/ your TV & Sonos? Also, revised answer - see above.